# Sankey diagram using d3.js - Add information to link title

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, sankey-diagram

I am trying to implement this sankey example: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/c9b90689c1438f57d649

It uses a CSV file for data input with the fields:

> source - target - value

The link title is displayed as: [image]

I would like to add another field to the data input:

> source - target - value - **information**

Which should be added to the link title as follows:
[image]

Do you see a way to add this information? I tried changing:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

// load the data (using the timelyportfolio csv method)
d3.csv("sankey.csv", function(error, data) {

//set up graph in same style as original example but empty
graph = {"nodes" : [], "links" : []};

data.forEach(function (d) {
  graph.nodes.push({ "name": d.source });
  graph.nodes.push({ "name": d.target });
  graph.links.push({ "source": d.source,
                     "target": d.target,
                     "value": +d.value,
                     **"information": +d.information**} });
 });

// add the link titles
link.append("title")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.source.name + " → " + 
            d.target.name + "\n" + format(d.value) + **d.information**; });
```

Which is unfortunately not working.

Comment: Can you share a fiddle of your work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't tell us exactly *how* it is not working. So, I'd guess the problem is the unary plus operator being used with strings... if my assumption is correct, you're probably seeing a `NaN` in the title.

Anyway, these are the steps:

First, add the field in the CSV:

```
source,target,value,info
Barry,Elvis,2,foo
Frodo,Elvis,2,bar
Frodo,Sarah,2,baz
Barry,Alice,2,foobar
Elvis,Sarah,2,foobaz
Elvis,Alice,2,barbar
Sarah,Alice,4,barbaz
```

Then, push the property in the links, **without** the unary plus:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
    graph.nodes.push({
        "name": d.source
    });
    graph.nodes.push({
        "name": d.target
    });
    graph.links.push({
        "source": d.source,
        "target": d.target,
        "value": +d.value,
        "information": d.info
    });
});
```

Finally, get the property in the title:

```
link.append("title")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.source.name + " → " +
            d.target.name + "\n" + format(d.value) + ", Information: " + d.information
    });
```

Here is the updated bl.ocks: http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/5652b4a53cd73f0b3a493b400ec4e1b3/2cdf75a83dc79946722f975144c0ce892836a15a